# wagtail 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'model'

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have install a fresh wagtail when I try to create a page I'm getting error :

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'model'
```

My class is :

```
class CategoryPage(Page):
    
    description_meta = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    template = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, default='_nixaTemplate/category/default.html')
    image = models.ImageField(_("Image"), upload_to="img/category/", blank=True, null=True)
    display = models.BooleanField(_("Display Post"), default=False )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldRowPanel([
            FieldPanel("description_meta", classname="col-12 col12"),
            FieldPanel("template", classname="col-12 col12"),
            ImageChooserPanel("image", classname="full"),
        ]),
    ]
```

when I try to create Category Page I get that message
[image]

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something

Comment: there is no solution I have a fresh installed wagtail

Comment: Please edit your question with the full stack trace for the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ImageChooserPanel` needs to be used with a `ForeignKey` to the Image model, not an `ImageField`. This is because Django's `ImageField` field type just provides a plain file upload, but in Wagtail images are database objects in their own right that can be re-used, given titles, organised into collections and so on.

```
class CategoryPage(Page):
    description_meta = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    template = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True, default='_nixaTemplate/category/default.html')
    image = models.ForeignKey(("wagtailimages.Image"), blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    display = models.BooleanField(_("Display Post"), default=False )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldRowPanel([
            FieldPanel("description_meta", classname="col-12 col12"),
            FieldPanel("template", classname="col-12 col12"),
            ImageChooserPanel("image", classname="full"),
        ]),
    ]
```

Alternatively, if you just want a plain file upload field here, you can use `FieldPanel` instead of `ImageChooserPanel`, but then the images will exist outside of the Wagtail image library and the standard image functionality (such as the `{% image %}` template tag) won't be usable for them.